# How cookies are managed by networking code

Tags: function, go, cookies

I was recently migrating over from C# and looking to create some of my old applications. As such I have needed to find a way to manage sessions within Go web requests. I found a solution in the form of this code:

```
// Jar is session object struct - cookie jar including mutex for syncing
type Jar struct {
    sync.Mutex
    cookies map[string][]*http.Cookie
}

// NewJar is a function for creating cookie jar for use
func NewJar() *Jar {
    jar := new(Jar)
    jar.cookies = make(map[string][]*http.Cookie)
    return jar
}

// SetCookies sets the cookies for the jar
func (jar *Jar) SetCookies(u *url.URL, cookies []*http.Cookie) {
    jar.Lock()
    if _, ok := jar.cookies[u.Host]; ok {
        for _, c := range cookies {
            jar.cookies[u.Host] = append(jar.cookies[u.Host], c)
        }
    } else {
        jar.cookies[u.Host] = cookies
    }
    jar.Unlock()
}

// Cookies returns cookies for each host
func (jar *Jar) Cookies(u *url.URL) []*http.Cookie {
    return jar.cookies[u.Host]
}

// NewJarClient creates new client, utilising a NewJar()
func NewJarClient() *http.Client {

    proxyURL, _ := url.Parse("http://127.0.0.1:8888")

    tr := &http.Transport{
        MaxIdleConns:       10,
        IdleConnTimeout:    30 * time.Second,
        DisableCompression: true,
        Proxy:              http.ProxyURL(proxyURL),
    }

    return &http.Client{
        Jar:       NewJar(),
        Transport: tr,
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is in understanding how this works. I create a client doing the following

```
client := NewJarClient()
```

but then when I issue networking fuctions using it such as a get request, the cookies automatically carry on and it all works as planned. The problem is  Ihave no idea why. I see no mention of methods such as the Cookies one or the `SetCookies` one ever being called and it seems to just handle each one by magically running the functions. Could someone annotate or explain the given methods line by line or in a way so that they'd make better sense to me coming over from a C# background. Thanks :)

Comment: To see how [http.Client](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client) uses the cookie jar cmd/ctrl+f through [this file](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/client.go) for "Jar", "Cookies", or "SetCookies". For example `SetCookies` appears only once [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/client.go#L182).

Comment: Oh so the method I've created above is a form of extension method on that? Sorry if I'm not following, will take a closer look at your links. So essentially what is going on is when the client calls a method and the response contains cookies, the set cookie bit is run? Which I have extended.

Comment: `NewJar` allocates and returns a new instance of type `*Jar`, now type `*Jar`, thanks to the methods defined on it, implements the interface called `CookieJar`, implicitly. `http.Client` has a field called `Jar` which is defined as having the type `CookieJar`, that means that you can set `http.Client.Jar` to anything that implements the `CookieJar` interface. The `NewJarClient` function returns a new `*http.Client` instance with it's `Jar` field set to `*Jar` instance returned from `NewJar`. This allows the client to use `*Jar`'s methods without really knowing it's a `*Jar`, it only...

Comment: .. it only cares about the methods, which are then called by the `http.Client` when sending request. It doesn't matter what those `CookieJar` methods do, you can implement them to do anything. `http.Client` then calls your methods providing the parameters and handling the returned values how it sees fit.

Comment: Perfect. That makes a lot more sense. I really appreciate it. Is there any way I can mark this question as solved using your comment as an answer? I'm new to stack and I don't see an option to close it based on your reply :)

Comment: No problem, I'll turn the comments into a real answer.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for all the help!

Comment: Please consider using the std cookie jar in net/http/cookiejar instead of your own hand-rolled one. Cookie handling is tricky.

Comment: @Volker is this in reference to my NewJar method? So that one should be replaced with the standard implementation of the cookiejar, correct? :)

Comment: @JordanAllen. Yes. Do not use your own (which is broken) but use a correct one, e.g. the one in the std lib.

Comment: Yes, just noticed mine is broke in the sense that when new cookies are set with the same name as existing ones. Instead of overwriting, the cookies are instead set again, leading to duplicate cookies. The standard lib doesn't allow for maintaining cookies across requests does it? So the rest of my implementation would remain the same aside from the NewJar? Sorry - new to the language @Volker

Comment: @JordanAllen Sorry for the drastic words but your implementation is completely broken, it is far of what a RFC 6265 compliant cookie jar would look like. Both methods Cookies and SetCookies are wrong (e.g. they handle paths wrong, ignore all flags, domain handling is missing, expiration is ignored, etc, pp) Please: Do not even try rolling your own. Use the standard one which does absolutely everything (of course it will "maintaining cookies across requests" because that is the _job_ of a cookie jar) and in a correct way.

Comment: @JordanAllen Try running the test cases of the std cookie jar implementation against your jar and see what is wrong. (Basically everything).

Comment: @Volker honestly I appreciate the drastic words. Will help stop me running into just as drastic problems. I was under the impression there was no way to maintain sessions in requests without having to create my own version. Maybe the sources I used for research were dated or just as ill-informed as myself. I'll look for some ways to utilise the standard cookiejar. Thanks

Comment: @Volker Got it all working now, going to answer my own question with a solution as I was looking for session maintenance across requests. Assumed for some reason I couldn't do it - not sure where I got that idea. got it working perfectly now with the standard implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NewJar` allocates and returns a new instance of type `*Jar`, now type `*Jar`, thanks to the methods defined on it, implements the interface called `CookieJar`, implicitly.

The `http.Client` type has a field called `Jar` which is defined as having the type `CookieJar`, that means that you can set `http.Client.Jar` to anything that implements the `CookieJar` interface, including the `*Jar` type. The `NewJarClient` function returns a new `*http.Client` instance with it's `Jar` field set to the `*Jar` instance returned by `NewJar`.

This allows the returned client value to use `*Jar`'s methods without really knowing that it's a `*Jar`, it only knows that the value in its `Jar` field has the same set of methods as those defined by the `CookieJar` interface.

So the `http.Client` instance, when sending requests, uses your `*Jar` by calling its methods providing the parameters and handling the returned values. How your `*Jar` is used by the client is an implementation detail of the `http.Client` type and you don't have to worry about that. You just need to make sure that the methods that implement the `CookieJar` interface do what you want them to do, how and when they are called is up to the client.

But if you're interested in the implementation details of the client anyway, you can check out the source file of [http.Client](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/client.go).

Answer (score 0):

Due to misinformation in the form of a few dated blog posts, I came to the impression that I was unable to maintain cookies across requests in go - for some weird reason. Having thought that, I researched and looked into creating my own implementation which ca be seen above. It's been brought to my attention that my implementation is completely broken and flawed and that the standard http library itself can perfectly handle maintaining cookies, simply by including a value for the `Jar` when creating a client. For example:

```
jar, _ := cookiejar.New(nil)

proxyURL, _ := url.Parse("http://127.0.0.1:8888")

tr := &http.Transport{
    MaxIdleConns:       10,
    IdleConnTimeout:    30 * time.Second,
    DisableCompression: true,
    Proxy:              http.ProxyURL(proxyURL),
}

c := &http.Client{
    Jar:       jar,
    Transport: tr,
}
```